# Get the n digit of the sequence

Tags: php, loops

To be honest this is a school task.
The task is:

We need to generate consecutive numbers like this : 123456789101112131415161718192021...

Find the 1.000.000th digit
Find the 1.000.000.000th digit
Find the 1.000.000.000.000th digit

Here's the code I wrote:

```
<?php
ini_set('max_execution_time', 3600);
ini_set("memory_limit", "512M");

function getDigit($n)
{
    $count = 1;
    (string) $a = '';
    while (strlen($a) <= $n) {
        $a .= $count;
        $count++;
    }

    $answer = substr($a, ($n - 1), 1);
    echo "The {$n}th digit is: {$answer} <br>";
}

$start = microtime(TRUE); //Start Time Execution

getDigit(1000000000);

$page_time = round(microtime(TRUE) - $start, 3) + '0.02'; // Get the time it took for the page to load
echo $page_time . "<br>"; // Display the total time it took to load the page
```

The code is working fine and can solve the problem for the 1.000.000 and 1.000.000.000 digit. But at 1.000.000.000.000 digit, I got an connection time out error from my browser. 

My question is: Is there's anyway to optimize my code so it can run faster?

Comment: May I suggest you treat the number as a string, load the digits into an array, and just reference the array location?

Comment: There are some constants you can generate beforehand: all the single digit numbers (1-9) make a string that's of length 9. All the two-digit numbers (10-99) make a string that's length 180, total: 189. And so on. You can begin your search much, much later.

Comment: There is a more efficient way than simply constructing an enormous string and counting through every digit. You can solve this purely mathematically. Think about this: You can easily calculate how many numbers have 1 digit, how many have 2 digits, and so on. You can add the numbers of digits together until you get to your target, and then extrapolate what number you are at.

Comment: If the problem is that it times out, then run it from the command line where it doesn't matter how long it runs.

Comment: @AndyLester yep, who cares about performance ?

Comment: Execution speed is not always important.  If this is homework, and it only needs to run once, then perhaps the OP doesn't care so long as it finishes in, say, less than 10 minutes.

Comment: @AndyLester: But `1.000.000.000.000` actually will never work, since the length of the generated string is at least `1.000.000.000.000` which results in storing more than **1 GiB** of (useless) data. Most VM's don't allows this amount of memory.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can iterate over the number length.

You know that the first nine numbers have length 1, the next 90 have length two, next 900 length three.

Thus you define a function:

```
$index = $input-1;
$rank = 9;
$size = 1;
$offset = 1;
while($index >= $rank*$size) {
    $offset *= 10;
    $index -= $rank*$size;
    $rank *= 10;
    $size++;
}
```

When that part of the algorithm ends, `$size` stores the size of the numbers of the "group" where your number is part of. And `$index` is reduced to the offset from the start of that group. Thus now we only need to determine about which number we are talking. This can be done using:

```
$ith = $index % $size;
$number = $offset+($index-$ith)/$size;
```

Finally we write out that number and get the appropriate digit:

```
$strnum = (string) $number;
echo $strnum{$ith};
```

or the full version:

```
$index = $input-1;
$rank = 9;
$size = 1;
$offset = 1;
while($index >= $rank*$size) {
    $offset *= 10;
    $index -= $rank*$size;
    $rank *= 10;
    $size++;
}
$ith = $index % $size;
$number = $offset+($index-$ith)/$size;
$strnum = (string) $number;
echo $strnum{$ith};
```

---

Note that the proposed method does not *enumerate* over all the integers. We simply determine how much characters the total group of numbers with *k* digits will take and if we can skip this, we simply do. Next we calculate where exactly we will stop in the group.

One can of course not use this method for a generic sequence, but one can exploit properties on the proposed sequence.

This method will work in **log**-time (log in the number represented by the input), because at each iteration in the `while` loop, the rank increases exponentially. Furthermore the method uses **log**-memory (the string it needs to store), this can even be further reduced.

Generating a string like you did is not a good solution: it will take linear time and eventually your machine will run out of memory when storing the entire string (furthermore storing already visited numbers is pretty useless).

Based on this, you can precompute the values you need and define a lookup table.

Comment: Kudos for a nice, general, and almost-optimal answer. On the other hand, the question is only asking for 3 values. You can precalculate them and have a program consisting of 3 output statements.

Comment: Indeed, you can use a LUT, but first in order to generate the LUT, you will need some kind of algorithm and furthermore in my opinion if such questions are asked, one is merely looking for a way how to compute them I guess? I think there was one user answering the question using the LUT method, I did not downvote this. By showing how to calculate the numbers however, the user can generate a LUT for all the inputs that he ever expects to be usefull.

Comment: You sir are awesome. My code run about 90 seconds for the 1.000.000.000th digit. But your code run in instant. Thank you very much for the great knowledge.

Comment: CommuSoft - nobody downvoted, and I for one upvoted. My comment was tongue-in-cheek. On the other hand, please check your answer for correctness. With the slow algorithm, the 101th digit is a 5. For you, it is a 1 (!!).

Comment: Fixed. Thanks. @user3708043: there was a small error, now it is fixed. You of course need to multiply with the size.

Comment: Now it fails at 191 (correct is 0, you output 1). Test harness at https://ideone.com/LsWTwr (in C++, because that is what I had handy).

Comment: @tucuxi: second fix, I used an offset now, this makes things way easier. Do you still see errors?

Comment: @user3708043: second fix, such algorithms are somtimes hard in the details.

Comment: @tucuxi: I've tested it myself and it seems to work correct now.

Comment: Tested up to 10k - seems to work fine. Kudos for fixing, and a small flick behind the ears for not testing it right from the very beginning (otoh, I should have tested before upvoting too...).

Comment: Sorry, furthermore my first comment was not meant to be offensive. It was just a remark that there is not much added value to simply return three digits that are the right answers. If someone would ask what the result of `2*x+3=0` is, one better explains how to solve a linear equation...

Comment: Got this error for the 1.000.000.000.000th digit.Notice: Uninitialized string offset: -3 in test.php on line 30. The line is `echo $strnum{$ith};`

Comment: @user3708043: if I run the code here, it actually works: http://writecodeonline.com/php/. Furthermore that errors should be impossible since $index is guaranteed to remain positive (we only subtract if the number is still positive and a modulo operation will never result in a negative value. I've also tested the code very extensively now.

Comment: It's odd. I try run the code on remote hosting and my virtual machine and it run just fine. But not on my local xampp. Any thought?

Comment: Not immediately :(, I'm not really working with servers,... more on algorithms,... Sorry :(

Comment: It's ok. Again, thank you very much for giving such great knowledge and explanation.